# Reading Sim Number in Dual Sim Phone Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

Im always getting an error of Java.Lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10710 nor current process has android.permission.READ_SMS. Even if I already Added the READ_SMS in AndroidManifest.xml

MyCode:

```
public string GetNumber()
{
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
    return telephonyManager.Line1Number;
}
```

Thanks in Advance and Good Day :D

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305407/android-dual-sim-card-api). What API are you targeting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get phone number from device inspite of declaring required permissions in android manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018388/unable-to-get-phone-number-from-device-inspite-of-declaring-required-permissions)

Comment: but in Java how do i do it in Xamarin.Form

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks a lot you are really a great help thanks man :D

Comment: @hvaughan3 Im targetting  API15 to API 23

Comment: Anything below API22 and dual sims is a custom feature and anything at API23 or above and you have to request permission at runtime... gotta love the Android APIs... ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover request permission at runtime you mean at AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @jaketalledo In the manifest AND for API23+ requesting permission at runtime... I'll add an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *really simple* runtime permission request example.

I would highly recommend reading the Xamarin blog post and the Android doc linked below as you should show the user "why" you are requesting permission before the system dialog shows up.

```
[Activity(Label = "RunTimePermissions", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    const int PermissionSMSRequestCode = 99;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate { 
            if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 23) // Permissions accepted by the user during app install
                DoSomeWork();

            var permission = BaseContext.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReadSms);
            if (permission == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted) // Did the user already grant permission?
                DoSomeWork();
            else // Ask the user to allow/deny permission request
                RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadSms }, PermissionSMSRequestCode);
        };
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == PermissionSMSRequestCode)
        {
            if ((grantResults.Count() > 0) && (grantResults[0] == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted))
                DoSomeWork();
            else
                Log.Debug("PERM", "The user denied access!");
        }
    }

    protected void DoSomeWork()
    {
        Log.Debug("PERM", "We have permission, so do something with it");
    }
}
```

[image]

Ref: [Requesting Runtime Permissions in Android Marshmallow](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)

Ref: [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Thanks SushiHangover although I wasnt able to get the SIM number but my Sms sending without user interaction works using your runtime Permission sample thank you very much.